# grepl with loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, grepl

Saw some posts around just a general expression if 'value' contains 'char' but how can this be done over a length vector?

```
    v1 <- c('123','456','789','4433','77666')
    v2 <- c('9999','9998','91239','9987','8877666','789','100')
```

but when i do this function i want it to return ('T','F','T','F','T')

```
    df<-0
    for(i in 1:length(v1))
    {
    for(j in 1:length(v2))
    df[i]<-grepl(i,j)
    }
```

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: `sapply(v1, function(x) any(grepl(x, v2)))`?

Comment: nice good call yeah works way easier then looping!